# Price for registering visual studio express 2012 for web

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I had registered Visual Studio Express 2012 for web product. One credit card details is associated with my Microsoft account. I received the product id. I called Microsoft customer support and they told me it was a trial version, so they didn't charge me. Normally trial version will end within 30 days. After 30 days will they charge for that product?

Comment: All of the Express products are free.

Comment: You really should read the terms you accept, especially when entering CC details. BTW: suggested typo fix: trail -> trial.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not automatically because **Express Editions** are fully free and not limited in time.